# Pygame another thread not getting QUIT event?

Tags: python, multithreading, pygame

I'm making an game for ending my programming course and I sometimes have some longer scenes displayed and the loop ain't checking for if there is QUIT event and then stop everything and close the loop. So I thought multi-threading would help, but apparently it doesn't seem to get events, I have tried printing out - it gets events, but it simply aint getting QUIT event.

Here is the code:

```
from pygame import *
from threading import Thread

def closesearcher():
    global running
    while running:
        for i in event.get():
            if i.type == QUIT:
                print ("QUIT event in closesearcher")
                running = False
                quit()
                exit()
        clock.tick(60)

def main():
    init()
    #True while game is running
    global running
    running = True
    global window
    window = display.set_mode([640, 480])
    global clock
    clock = time.Clock()
    #Let's start closesearcher
    searcherclose = Thread(target = closesearcher)
    searcherclose.start()
    scenegame = gamescene()

def gamescene():
    #Render some scenery, wait for user to press button, etc in the following loop
    while running:
        for i in event.get():
            if i.type == QUIT:
                print ("QUIT event in game loop")
        clock.tick(60)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Any solutions that would be similiar to the structure of my current code?
Note: I use Python 3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about actually exiting the loops with `return` instead of only printing that you got the quit event?

Currently, you only exit the loop in `closesearcher` but not in `gamescene`.

Also, I think `event.get()` will remove the event. So calling get in the other loop will not return anything. You need to set a global flag `playerWantsToQuit` and use that instead of the local `running` variables.